# openstack Instance failed network setup

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have 2 ubuntu node (controller and compute) that i installed openstack, module by module.
but i can not create any instance.
in nova compute logs show this error:

`ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-42d9d648-b39f-4214-9e5e-b8fb8799c10e 91704884e43f48fcbd156b8d7429fc3e 5e055db0a5464dc1997ab0f456792271 - default default] Instance failed network setup after 1 attempt(s): keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:9696/v2.0/networks?id=163f0b54-e337-40ac-81af-958c24ceeb7f: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/networks?id=163f0b54-e337-40ac-81af-958c24ceeb7f (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4ce476a820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED')`

please help me

Comment: It looks as if nova compute is failing to reach the Neutron API server at `http://localhost:9696`. Is that the correct URL? Is the `neutron-api` service running? Can you connect to it using that URL?

Comment: To expand on @larsks's question: Since the compute node is not identical to the controller, `localhost` can't be the correct address of the Neutron server. I guess you misconfigured the neutron section in nova.conf on the compute node.

Comment: @larsks yes i can connect to this in my browser using that URL!

Comment: @berndbausch no! i configured that! and not use any```localhost``` on the compute node! i just used IP.

Comment: The error message says `Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:9696`. This URL must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: @berndbausch it says ```Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:9696/networks?id=<lan_net_id>``` and when i check this URL its say 404 ERROR! why?

Comment: You say that you checked the URL in your browser. I doubt that your compute node has a browser. Therefore, how, and more importantly where do you check this URL? Note that `localhost` literally means your local machine. Thus, if you check `localhost` from your PC, it refers to your PC, not the compute node.

Comment: @berndbausch i replaced ```localhost``` with controller IP in URL!   also when i replaced that with compute IP it say ```unable to connect```

Comment: How, and more importantly where do you check this URL?

Comment: also when i replaced that with compute IP it say ```unable to connect```

Comment: @berndbausch in my pc browser

Comment: When you test the URL, `localhost` is your PC. However, when nova-compute tries to access `localhost`, it is the compute node. This explains why accessing `localhost` has two different results.

Comment: @berndbausch so what must i do?!

Comment: Find out where on the compute host `localhost:9696` is configured. Or perhaps it is configured in the Keystone service catalog? It must be somewhere in your cloud.

Comment: do you attention to it say my network id after url !  so i think it cant connect newtork that i created!  @berndbausch

Comment: succeed!  my endpoints was wrong! and when i use IP along side ```localhost``` in endpoints, it worked. thank you for your time :)

Comment: Very good! My recommendation: You need to learn more about Networking. In my experience, networking problems are frequent in an OpenStack cloud.

Comment: yes my networking information is not enough!